# Computing Masking layer and using a few layers later in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, masking

I have an architecture that processes padded sequences of fixed length. For whatever reason, passing the mask through some of the intermediate layers doesn't work, so what I want is to:

1. Compute the mask right after the `Input` layer
2. Process the input with some other layers
3. Apply the mask before it goes into a GRU layer

Something like this

```py
x = layers.Input(shape=(sequenceLength, inputFeatures))
m = layers.Masking(mask_value=255)(x)
# x = SomeOtherLayers()(x) # some other layers
# Apply initial mask here
x = GRU()(x)
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I have tried adding a new mask and overwriting the `_keras_mask` attribute, but that didn't work

```py
x = layers.Input(shape=(sequenceLength, inputFeatures), name=name)
m = layers.Masking(mask_value=255)(x)
# x = SomeOtherLayers()(x) # some other layers
x = layers.Masking()(x)
x._keras_mask = m._keras_mask
x = GRU()(x)
```

Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: what kind of intermediate layers?

Comment: `Conv1D` layers. I don't think they support `Masking` as of now: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/411

Comment: You could apply your own mask. You just have to make sure that your mask is taken in account inside your loss function.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is using a custom function to get the mask :

```
def get_mask_from_lengths(lengths, max_len=None):
    if max_len is None:
        max_len = tf.reduce_max(lengths)
    ids = tf.range(0, max_len)
    mask = ids < lengths
    return mask
```

Then I define the model:

```
sequenceLength = 5
inputFeatures = 1

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(sequenceLength, inputFeatures))
lengths = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))  # vector containing the length of each element of the batch

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3)(inputs)  # some other layer
mask = get_mask_from_lengths(lengths=lengths)
output = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=2)(x, mask=mask)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, lengths], outputs=output)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

An example:

```
x1 = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([10, 3, 5, 3, 5]), (1, -1))
x2 = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([11, 9, 120, 255, 255]), (1, -1))
input_tensor = tf.concat([x1, x2], axis=0)
length_tensor = tf.reshape([5, 3], (-1, 1))  # first sequence x1 is full and x2 has three elements not equal to the masking value 255 (should create a function to get this tensor from input_tensor)
out_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 2))

model.fit([input_tensor, length_tensor], out_tensor, epochs=2)
```